# Visualforce page for the orders including the products

Tags: visualforce

This is my first question!! I am a beginner in SFDC and I am trying to create a visualforce page that will be related with my orders. The outcome would be the order name the account number and name and include all the products that I added to the order.

When I insert a date related record I get Thu Nov 06 00:00:00 GMT 2014 rather than just 6/11/2014
The date is a date function that you select only the date and not the time.
My code is something like :

```
<tr>    
    <td align="right"
        style="border-right-style: solid; border-reight-width: thin; border-right-color:#C017BE;" 
        width="20%">
        <i>Wedding Date</i>
    </td>
    <td width="80%">
        <b>{!relatedTo.Account.Wedding_Date__c}</b>
    </td>        
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the apex:outputText component to format the date:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}">
  <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Account.Wedding_Date__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

The full documentation for this component can be found at: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm

Comment: @TommyGeorgiou Please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: I am marking it as the solution. Actually I am a newbie and do not know if I have to press anything to get it marked!